# Missing Vector in QGIS toolbar

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, select-by-location

I have a laptop (TurboX flame u7 475) and I am using Endeavour OS.

I am using the Software QGIS and I want to use the 'select by location' option in Vector but I cant find it.

Is there any plugin I could install, or anything else i can do?

Comment: That tool is part of the select-toolbar.

Comment: In the Processing tools there is a group of tools called Vector Selection.

Comment: it is also available in the menu Vector>Research Tools>Select by Location...